# Countries are suddenly isolated, can they maintain/recover the current technology level?

Tags: society, technology, government

Let's say suddenly, today, transparent and invisible barriers appeared along the borders of all countries. Here are the mechanics of those barriers :

- They let air, light and animals pass, however, humans and things moved by humans cannot pass throught. For instance, if the wind uproot a tree near a border, it will fall normally. If a lumberer cut it, it will hit the barrier.
- For disputed territories, they are included in the country de facto governing it
- The sea borders correspond to the maritine boundaries, no one can enter (or leave if they were in at the moment the barrier appeared) international sea.
- Everything made by humans that is in the middle of a barrier (because it was there before they appeared) is cut like wires, internet cables or pipes.
- To simplify things, the entire earth is in a spherical barrier 5km up in the sky, preventing sending anything into space.

Clearly, there would be big disturbances at the beginning as almost all countries depend on import for different ressources. They might have some stockpiles but those are bound to run out.
Countries depending on imports for food might also get large famines. I'm expecting large and long duration power failures in many countries.

However, my question is, would it ever be possible to climb out of the hole ?

The geographically larges countries like Russia are advantaged, but I'm wondering about the smaller ones. Oil could be an issue, however we are getting to the point where electricity can replace it.
North Korea is close to this situation but they are still getting oil food from outside.

So my question is : Would all countries eventually manage to recover from the situation and get back to today within 100 years ? 
And if I'm wrong and it's far worse than I expect, would any country manage to adapt and keep a 2000+ tech level ?

Comment: This seems like another hypothetical what-if question, instead of world-building.

Answer (score 0):

**Never (or a very long time)**

Our entire economy is built on the assumption of global trade. From a technological point of view, it's theoretically possible to replace most individual missing resources (like your example of petroleum). But in a practical sense, we would have to completely start over with supply chains.

Let's use the United States as an example. It has one of the world's largest populations and some of the greatest natural resources (though I'm not sure how the barrier would treat Alaska). The Trump administration levied tariffs on goods imported from China. The government then reviewed applications from companies who argued that their products were impossible to make without imports. You can see some of the approved exemptions in [this PDF](https://www.strtrade.com/assets/htmldocuments/Product%20Specific%20Exclusions%20Granted%20-%20List%203.pdf). As [ProPublica](https://www.propublica.org/article/bibles-but-not-textbooks-trumps-tariff-exemptions-pick-winners-and-losers) pointed out, the list includes things like Bibles and salmon that we theoretically could manufacture in the United States. For decades after the barrier went into place, we'd be figuring out how to make things that we already have the resources and knowhow to make and that we may have manufactured en masse only a few decades ago. Even 100 years from now, we would likely not be back to 21st century technology, though by then we may have figured out how to make *"Nonwoven wipes, impregnated with organic surfactant preparations of a kind used to remove hair-color stains from the skin, put up for retail sale in canisters each containing 100 wipes."*

Comment: But we'd still be able to make them individually. We just wouldn't be able to mass produce.

Comment: @Halfthawed we could make some things individually, like salmon and Bibles. But computer chips and other advanced technology requires so many individual components and such long supply chains that I'm not optimistic.

Comment: Except the US produces computer chips already: https://www.axios.com/computer-chips-manufacturing-america--10dcfe13-64f3-4ea9-ad4a-cb189a00429a.html